# Docker In Docker IN Docker Compose (Networking Issues)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I literally cannot explain to you how hard it is to wrap my head around wanting to create a docker container that will be running docker that will be running my web server that will have access to my outer docker host.

So what I know so far:

- I have a dockerfile that when executed outside of a docker
  compose and tested with I can see that it connects to my host docker
  daemon!
- Next I move into my docker-compose setup and I understand I must be
  having an issue because of the networking that occurs inside of
  docker-compose files. But I have 0 docker-compose networking
  experience, so I ask how can I also attach my container to the
  default network once inside of this setup?

My Bash Script (Entrypoint):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e


# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- docker "$@"
fi

# if our command is a valid Docker subcommand, let's invoke it through Docker instead
# (this allows for "docker run docker ps", etc)
if docker help "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    set -- docker "$@"
fi

# if we have "--link some-docker:docker" and not DOCKER_HOST, let's set DOCKER_HOST automatically
if [ -z "$DOCKER_HOST" -a "$DOCKER_PORT_2375_TCP" ]; then
    export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://docker:2375'
fi

if [ "$1" = 'dockerd' ]; then
    cat >&2 <<-'EOW'
         Hey there!  It looks like you're trying to run a Docker daemon.
           You probably should use the "dind" image variant instead, something like:
             docker run --privileged --name some-overlay-docker -d docker:stable-dind --storage-driver=overlay
           See https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/ for more documentation and usage examples.
    EOW
    sleep 3
fi

docker version

dotnet ApiServer.dll
```

My compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  apiserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiserver
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./ApiServer/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
```

Lastly my dockerfile: (Shouldn't really need this but here it is)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-alpine AS base

COPY /ApiServer/modprobe.sh /usr/local/bin/modprobe
COPY /ApiServer/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN dos2unix -u /usr/local/bin/modprobe
RUN dos2unix -u /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ApiServer/ApiServer.csproj", "ApiServer/"]
COPY ["SharedLibs/SharedLibs.csproj", "SharedLibs/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ApiServer/ApiServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ApiServer"
RUN dotnet build "ApiServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ApiServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS docker
## Docker Setup
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        ca-certificates

# set up nsswitch.conf for Go's "netgo" implementation (which Docker explicitly uses)
# - https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/v17.09.0-ce/components/engine/hack/make.sh#L149
# - https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.9.1/src/net/conf.go#L194-L275
# - docker run --rm debian:stretch grep '^hosts:' /etc/nsswitch.conf
RUN [ ! -e /etc/nsswitch.conf ] && echo 'hosts: files dns' > /etc/nsswitch.conf

ENV DOCKER_CHANNEL stable
ENV DOCKER_VERSION 18.09.3
# TODO ENV DOCKER_SHA256
# https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/5b073ee2cf564edee5adca05eee574142f7627bb/components/packaging/static/hash_files !!
# (no SHA file artifacts on download.docker.com yet as of 2017-06-07 though)

RUN set -eux; \
    \
# this "case" statement is generated via "update.sh"
    apkArch="$(apk --print-arch)"; \
    case "$apkArch" in \
        x86_64) dockerArch='x86_64' ;; \
        armhf) dockerArch='armel' ;; \
        aarch64) dockerArch='aarch64' ;; \
        ppc64le) dockerArch='ppc64le' ;; \
        s390x) dockerArch='s390x' ;; \
        *) echo >&2 "error: unsupported architecture ($apkArch)"; exit 1 ;;\
    esac; \
    \
    if ! wget -O docker.tgz "https://download.docker.com/linux/static/${DOCKER_CHANNEL}/${dockerArch}/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz"; then \
        echo >&2 "error: failed to download 'docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}' from '${DOCKER_CHANNEL}' for '${dockerArch}'"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
    \
    tar --extract \
        --file docker.tgz \
        --strip-components 1 \
        --directory /usr/local/bin/ \
    ; \
    rm docker.tgz; \
    \
    dockerd --version; \
    docker --version

FROM docker AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["../usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dockerfile` exposes port **80**, but you are not mapping it in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Try updating the `docker-compose-yml` file to the following:

**`docker-compose-yml`**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  apiserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiserver
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./ApiServer/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

The ports key, will map ports from your host machine to the container. Simplified syntax:

```
    ports:
      - <hostport>:<containerport>
```

When starting a container with docker-compose, docker will create a new bridge network for your application stack. The containers in this network are not accessible from the host, and the containers inside the network cannot address the host either. This is why you need the port mapping - it will map the port `8080` on the host machine to the port `80` of the container.

You can then address the exposed service in the container with http://localhost:8080 from the host machine.

## Update

From your comment, I gather that you may have other services running on the host that you want to be able to connect to from inside the ApiServer container, like a database. There is one quick solution to this I guess, and that is connecting the new container to the "host" network.

You can try updating your docker-compose.yml file to this:

**`docker-compose-yml`**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  apiserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiserver
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./ApiServer/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    network_mode: "host"
```

The effect of this is, that when you resolve `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` from inside your container - you will actually get the hostmachine. This does not work if you deploy your container to a swarm though.

Comment: So my problem is that my container apiservice needs to be able to connect to the host os not through mapping but be on the same network. That is because my application will eventually have a database and such and so it's inside a compose right now. My apiservice needs to be connected to the new bridge network and the original host level default bridge network.

Comment: If you are getting a specific error, then please include it.

Comment: I don't thats the problem :/ if I run the container outside of docker-compose I get what I am looking for. If I run the container with docker-compose it just never connects to my host daemon.

Comment: What command are you using when running it without docker-compose?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Is there anything I can do to help? Was the information/solution helpful?